# Volume control keys not working after upgrading to ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, volume-control

My volume control keys are not working after updrading to ubuntu 17.04 .I tried some of the tricks from the previous replies and my speakers started working but my volume control keys are not yet working !!!